# Select distinct rows "modulo null"

Tags: sql, presto

Suppose I have a table `mytable`:

```
a     b     c     d     
------------------------
1     2     3     4
1     1     1     null
1     2     3     4
1     null  null  null
1     2     null  null
1     null  1     null
null  null  null  null
```

Now the first and third rows of this table are exact duplicates. However, we can also think of the fifth row as duplicating the information contained the first row, in the sense that `1 2 null null` is just a copy of `1 2 3 4` but with some data missing. Let's say that `1 2 null null` *is covered by* `1 2 3 4`.

"Covering by" is a relationship like `<=`, while "exact duplication" is a relationship like `==`. In the table above, we also have that the sixth row is covered by the second row, the fourth row is covered by all other rows except for the last, the last row is covered by all other rows, and the first and third rows are covered by each other.

Now I want to deduplicate `mytable` using this notion of covering. Said differently, I want the "minimal cover." That means that whenever row1 <= row2, row1 should be removed from the result. In this case, the outcome is

```
a     b     c     d     
------------------------
1     2     3     4
1     1     1     null
```

This is like `SELECT DISTINCT`, but with enhanced null-handling behavior.

More formally, we can define `deduplicate(table)` as the subset of rows of `table` such that:

- for every row *r* of `table`, there exists a row *c* of `deduplicate(table)` such that *r* <= *c*, and
- if *c1* and *c2* are any two separate rows in `deduplicate(table)`, then *c1* <= *c2* does *not* hold.

Or algorithmically:

```
def deduplicate(table):
  outcome = set()
  for nextRow in table:
    if any(nextRow <= o for o in outcome):
      continue
    else:
      for possiblyNowADuplicate in outcome:
        if possiblyNowADuplicate <= nextRow:
          # it is now a duplicate
          outcome.remove(possiblyNowADuplicate)
      outcome.add(nextRow)
  return outcome
```

How can I do this in SQL?

(I'm working in Presto, which allegedly implements modern ANSI SQL; moreover, the table I'm working with has many more columns and tons more rows than `mytable`, so the solution has to scale reasonably well, both in code complexity (ideally should not require code length O(n^2) in the number of columns!), and in terms of execution time.)

**Edit:** Based on @toonice's response, I have the following refinements:

- On further reflection, it'd be nice if the query code length were O(1) in the number of columns (possibly excluding a single explicit naming of the columns to be operated on in a subtable select, for maintainability). Having a complex boolean condition for each column in both a group by and an order by is a bit much. I'd have to write a python script to generate my sql query. It may be that this is unavoidable, however.
- I am operating on at least millions of rows. I cannot do this in O(n^2) time. So:

  - Is it possible to do this faster?
  - If not, I should mention that in my real dataset, I have a nonnull column "userid" such that each userid has at most say 100 rows associated with it. Can we take advantage of this segmentation to do the quadratic stuff only over each userid, and then recombine the data all back together? (And there are 60k users, so I definitely cannot name them explicitly in the query.)

Comment: Do you have something like an id column to uniquely identify a record?

Comment: @maraca, unfortunately no. Conceptually, the thing I'm trying to deduplicate are metadata entries in a logging table.

Comment: Could you provide an SQLite-`.dump` version of an example db? The differences between SQL and SQLite might prevent that, I know. But if it is possible it would make a great [mcve]. Also, do you have a query which *almost* gets done what you want?

Comment: @Yunnosch, I'd have to figure out how to use SQLite to do that. :D As for your second question, when I asked, I had no idea how to do this at all.

Comment: @Harrison I understand. I knew that sometimes moving to SQLite is not simple (even for SQL gurus). May I turn it into recommendation to play with SQLite? Sometimes your own planning/designing gets simpler with it as a convenient toy. The act of separating the SQL(ite) part out of a problem is extremely helpful. It is like [rubber ducking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) with a rubber duck who actually has some understanding of what you are talking about.

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following...

```
SELECT DISTINCT leftTable.a,
                leftTable.b,
                leftTable.c,
                leftTable.d
FROM tblTable AS leftTable
JOIN tblTable AS rightTable ON ( ( leftTable.a = rightTable.a OR
                                   rightTable.a IS NULL ) AND
                                 ( leftTable.b = rightTable.b OR
                                   rightTable.b IS NULL ) AND
                                 ( leftTable.c = rightTable.c OR
                                   rightTable.c IS NULL ) AND
                                 ( leftTable.d = rightTable.d OR
                                   rightTable.d IS NULL ) )
GROUP BY rightTable.a,
         rightTable.b,
         rightTable.c,
         rightTable.d
ORDER BY ISNULL( leftTable.a ),
         leftTable.a DESC,
         ISNULL( leftTable.b ),
         leftTable.b DESC,
         ISNULL( leftTable.c ),
         leftTable.c DESC,
         ISNULL( leftTable.d ),
         leftTable.d DESC;
```

This statement starts by performing an `INNER JOIN` on two copies of `tblTable`, which I have given the aliases of `leftTable` and `rightTable`.  This join will append a copy of each record from `rightTable` to every record in `leftTable` where the record from `leftTable` *covers* that from `rightTable`

The resulting dataset is then grouped to eliminate any duplicate entries in the fields from `leftTable`.

The grouped dataset is then ordered into descending order, with surviving `NULL` values being placed after non-`NULL` values.

*Extension*

You can use `SELECT DISTINCT leftTable.*` on the first line if you are happy with selecting all fields from `leftTable` - I've just gotten in the habit of listing the fields.  Either will work just fine in this case.  `leftTable.*` may prove more wieldy if you are dealing with a large number of fields.  I'm not sure if there is a difference in execution time bewteen the two methods.

I have not been able to find a way to say where all fields equal in a `WHERE` clause, either by saying `leftTable.* = rightTable.*` or something equivalent.  Our situation is further complicated by the fact that we are not testing for *equivalence*, but for *covering*.  Whilst I'd love it if there is a way to test for covering en masse, I'm afraid that you will just have to do a lot of copying, pasting and carefully changing letters so that the test used for each field in my Answer is applied to each of your fields.

Also, I have not been able to find a way to `GROUP BY` all fields, either in the order that they occur in the table or in any order, short of specifying every field to be grouped on.  This too would be nice to know, but for now I think you will have to specify each field from `rightTable`.  Seek out the glories and beware the dangers of copy, paste and edit!

If you do not care about if a row is ordered first or last when the value it is being ordered on is `NULL`, then you can speed up the statement slightly by removing the `ISNULL()` conditions from the `ORDER BY` clause.

If you do not care about ordering at all you can further speed up the statement by removing the `ORDER BY` clause entirely.  Depending on the quirks of your language, you will want to replace it with either nothing or with `ORDER BY NULL`.  Some languages, such as MySQL, automatically sort by the fields specified in a `GROUP BY` clause unless an `ORDER BY` clause is specified.  `ORDER BY NULL` is effectively a way of telling it not to do any sorting.

If we are only deduplicating covered records for each user (i.e. each user's records have no bearing on the records of other users), then the following statement should be used...

```
SELECT DISTINCT leftTable.userid,
                leftTable.a,
                leftTable.b,
                leftTable.c,
                leftTable.d
FROM tblTable AS leftTable
JOIN tblTable AS rightTable ON ( leftTable.userid = rightTable.userid AND
                                 ( leftTable.a = rightTable.a OR
                                   rightTable.a IS NULL ) AND
                                 ( leftTable.b = rightTable.b OR
                                   rightTable.b IS NULL ) AND
                                 ( leftTable.c = rightTable.c OR
                                   rightTable.c IS NULL ) AND
                                 ( leftTable.d = rightTable.d OR
                                   rightTable.d IS NULL ) )
GROUP BY rightTable.userid,
         rightTable.a,
         rightTable.b,
         rightTable.c,
         rightTable.d
ORDER BY leftTable.userid,
         ISNULL( leftTable.a ),
         leftTable.a DESC,
         ISNULL( leftTable.b ),
         leftTable.b DESC,
         ISNULL( leftTable.c ),
         leftTable.c DESC,
         ISNULL( leftTable.d ),
         leftTable.d DESC;
```

By eliminating in a dataset that large the need to join other user's records to that of each user, you are removing alot of processing overhead, *more* than is created by now needing to choose another field for output *and* by testing another pair of fields when joining *and* by adding another layer of grouping *and* by having to `ORDER BY` another field.

I'm afraid that I can not think of any other way to make this statement more efficient.  If anyone does know of a way, then I would like to hear about it.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

*Appendix*

This code was tested in `MySQL` using a dataset created using the following script...

```
CREATE TABLE tblTable
(
    a   INT,
    b   INT,
    c   INT,
    d   INT
);
INSERT INTO tblTable ( a,
                       b,
                       c,
                       d )
VALUES ( 1,    2,    3,    4    ),
       ( 1,    1,    1,    NULL ),
       ( 1,    2,    3,    4    ),
       ( 1,    NULL, NULL, NULL ),
       ( 1,    2,    NULL, NULL ),
       ( 1,    NULL, NULL, NULL ),
       ( NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL );
```

Comment: I had to try this code, and it works fine ... but given the join conditions, can't the first part just be `select distinct leftTable.*`

Comment: Well, that's just what I get from trying to be clever!  Thank you for pointing this out - I have improved (and tested) my answer from your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks! This answer is nifty. What you're doing conceptually seems to be:

    select left.*
    from tbl as left join tbl as right on left.* >= right.*
    group by right.*
    order by [choose the biggest left.* in the group]

However, I have like 30 columns I need to do this on. I know I asked for query length less than O(n^2) in my original question, but on viewing this, it seems that what I should really have asked for is O(1). Do you think this is possible?